# JQM popup not showing correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using JQM 1.3.1. I have a page that displays a list of items and next to each item there is a button that when clicked, shows a popup with some general info:

[image]

**IMPORTANT** : I need the popup to appear next to the pressed button

The problem is that when the object is on the bottom of the page, the popup appears cut and there is no way to scroll down:

[image]

here is the code that displays the popup:

```
$('.capbPlanDetailsPopup').popup('open', {
                positionTo: 'origin',
                x: btn.offset().left + btn.outerWidth() + 15,
                y: btn.offset().top - 35
            }); // pos is width/2 + width of menu image
```

Comment: And what do you think is problem here? Popup is showing where you want it to show.

Comment: Position it to window.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that I need the popup to appear next to the pressed button. Updated the question.

Comment: @Gajotres - the problem is i want it to show next to the pressed button, but  i also want the user to be able to scroll and see the entire popup

Comment: Is the main page scrollable at that point? I am talking about page below popup overlay.

Comment: @Gajotres - yes, it is scrollable. but the problem is the overlay isn't.

Comment: Then you need first to scroll to the pressed button before opening the popup.

Answer (score 1):

Found a possible solution, JQM provides a [tolerance](http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#option-tolerance) option, which enables you to set how closes to the window edge you allow the popup to appear:

```
//the popup height is 240px
$('.capbPlanDetailsPopup').popup({tolerance: "0,0,240,0" });
```

Although not the best solution since at the bottom the popup will not appear right next to the button, but it will do for now